# workaround for innerHTML = 'null' when window loads

Tags: javascript

I'm building an app with ES5 JS just for practice and "fun" where I store websites in `localStorage` then print them out on the page, i.e. a bookmarker application.

I'm getting a

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

error in the console when I run the following code:

**index.html**

```
  <body onload="fetchBookmarks()">

    <div class="container">
        ...some code
      </div>

      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h2>Bookmark Your Favorite Sites</h2>
        <form id="myForm">
            ...some code
        </form>
      </div>

      <div class="row marketing">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div id="bookmarksResults"></div> /* problem code */
        </div>
      </div>

      <footer class="footer">
        <p>&copy; 2018 Bookmarker</p>
      </footer>

    </div>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
```

**index.js**

```
...someJScode that stores the websites in localStorage
function fetchBookmarks() {
    var bookmarks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bookmarks'));

    //Get output id
    var bookmarksResults = document.getElementById('#bookmarksResults');

    bookmarksResults.innerHTML = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < bookmarks.length; i++) {
        var name = bookmarks[i].name;
        var url = bookmarks[i].url;

        bookmarksResults.innerHTML += name;
    }

}
```

now, the error is obviously because I am loading the `<body>` before the `<div id="bookmarksResults"></div>` so `innerHTML` responds with `null`

But two things here:

1) When I assign `onload="fetchBookmarks()"` to the `<footer>` element, the function doesn't run.
2) The tututorial I am following has this code almost exactly and it runs there.

I've also tried running the `fetchBookmarks()` function like this:

```
 window.onload = function() {
            fetchBookmarks();
            function fetchBookmarks(){
                ...some JS code
            };
        }
```

But that returned the same

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

So I'm a bit lost here and am much more interested in figuring out **why** this isn't working and the theory behind it so I understand JS better (the whole point of building this app in the first place).

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks SO team.

Comment: Notice the **of** in `Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null`. means that you are trying to access `null.innerHTML`, not that `innerHTML` is returning`null`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
document.getElementById('#bookmarksResults')
```

You don't need to prefix the ID with `#` when you're using it with `document.getElementById`. Either you may remove the `#` from the method call, or use `document.querySelector()`, which works the same way, but support CSS-like selectors to select elements from DOM.

```
document.getElementById('bookmarksResults');
// OR
document.querySelector('#bookmarksResults');
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to pass the value of the `id` without the `#`

Update from

```
var bookmarksResults = document.getElementById('#bookmarksResults');
```

to

```
var bookmarksResults = document.getElementById('bookmarksResults');
```